# Magnet near 2020 Macbook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro

So I recently got a cool portable monitor, the travel case/stand of which as a magnet to hold the monitor upright and in place. I wasn't thinking and put my computer on top of the monitor while it was in it's case, kind of like a bookstand. I noticed a weird noise (like a 'computing' sound if you will) coming from the machine and assumed it was just the intensive processes I was running. It started to get quite annoying until I realized that the noise went away when I removed the laptop from off the case. I also regularly travel with the folded case and computer in close proximity. Am I endangering my computer by having this case anywhere around it? Is there anyway to check for damage? I seem to have all my files and the computer works fine.

Comment: For a recent experience see https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/415914/i-put-a-magnet-over-the-mac-book-pro-2011

Answer (score 1):

No, a permanent magnet of any reasonable size would not damage your computer.

You are not endangering your computer by having the case near the computer.

The SSD in your computer is not affected by magnets of that type at all.

Comment: And as far as the recreatable noise that follows upon contact?

Comment: My guess would be that it's pulling the fans against the casing - shouldn't cause permanent damage but I would avoid doing that going forward.

Comment: Hmm, the fan blades are made of plastic, so they're not pulled by the magnet - but the center of the fan contains metal - however it is a long way from the monitor, so I doubt that you can in any way pull on that by a magnet near the monitor.

Comment: @goat Regarding the noise: Make a recording of the noise - together with a video demonstrating where you hold the magnet.

Comment: @jksoegaard in this case, I was placing the computer on top of the magnet.

Answer (score 1):

Permanent magnets have no significant effect on SSD drive based Macs, but note that this is **NOT correct** for a Mac with a spinning hard drive; a magnet could permanently delete data on that hard drive.

It can likely impact speaker sound (or cause speaker sound) as the speakers have tiny magnets themselves. It likely won't harm the speaker (it could pull the speaker cone beyond its range and break it, if there is enough travel room) but as your experience proves, you might hear weird sounds.  Since there are really no other moving parts and DRAM etc are not magnetic in nature, there are few things in current Macs that are impacted by strong magnets.

Also note that Macs include permanent magnets in their screen and base, to enable the screen to turn off when closed, so having magnets nearby is not an issue.